# Join 2 JSON objects with different primary keys with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

I have 2 json arrays and i need to join them together.

But how do you join 2 JSON arrays with JAvascript with different key value (ServerName and ComputerName) ?

```
var servers = {
  0:{ServerName:"PC1", OS:"Windows", PRPName: "NO_PRP", SLA: "gold"}, 
  1:{ServerName:"PC2", OS:"Linux", PRPName: "NO_PRP", SLA: "silver"},
  2:{ServerName:"PC3", OS:"Windows", PRPName: "NO_PRP", SLA: "bronz"},
  3:{ServerName:"PC4", OS:"Windows", PRPName: "NO_PRP", SLA: "gold"}, 
  4:{ServerName:"PC5", OS:"Linux", PRPName: "NO_PRP", SLA: "bronz"},
  5:{ServerName:"PC6", OS:"Windows", PRPName: "NO_PRP", SLA: "bronz"}
};

var computers = {
  0:{Name:"PC1", location:"Amsterdam", PatchStatus: "true", RebootPending: "true"}, 
  1:{Name:"PC2", location:"London", PatchStatus: "true", RebootPending: "true"},
  2:{Name:"PC3", location:"Berlin", PatchStatus: "true", RebootPending: "false"},
  3:{Name:"PC4", location:"Berlin", PatchStatus: "false", RebootPending: "true"},
  4:{Name:"PC5", location:"London", PatchStatus: "true", RebootPending: "false"},
  5:{Name:"PC6", location:"Amsterdam", PatchStatus: "true", RebootPending: "true"}
};
```

**The outcome needs to be:**

```
var endresult= {
  0:{Name:"PC1", location:"Amsterdam", PatchStatus: "true", RebootPending: "true", OS:"Windows", PRPName: "NO_PRP", SLA: "gold"}, 
  1:{Name:"PC2", location:"London", PatchStatus: "true", RebootPending: "true", OS:"Linux", PRPName: "NO_PRP", SLA: "silver"},
  2:{Name:"PC3", location:"Berlin", PatchStatus: "true", RebootPending: "false", OS:"Windows", PRPName: "NO_PRP", SLA: "bronz"},
  3:{Name:"PC4", location:"Berlin", PatchStatus: "false", RebootPending: "true", OS:"Windows", PRPName: "NO_PRP", SLA: "gold"},
  4:{Name:"PC5", location:"London", PatchStatus: "true", RebootPending: "false", OS:"Linux", PRPName: "NO_PRP", SLA: "bronz"},
  5:{Name:"PC6", location:"Amsterdam", PatchStatus: "true", RebootPending: "true", OS:"Windows", PRPName: "NO_PRP", SLA: "bronz"}
};
```

Comment: how did you some out with Windows2008 from windows? since keys are different what is join logic. There are different types of join.( Inner, left, right, full)

Comment: that was wrong i edit my post.

Comment: i have edit my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate over computers array and use [Array.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to find matching servers by comparing name properties.

Then merge two entries with [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

```js
var servers = {
"servers":[
  {"ServerName":"PC1", "OS":"Windows"}, 
  {"ServerName":"PC2", "OS":"Linux"},
  {"ServerName":"PC3", "OS":"Windows"}
]
}

var computers = {
"computers":[
  {"ComputerName":"PC1", "location":"Amsterdam"}, 
  {"ComputerName":"PC2", "location":"London"},
  {"ComputerName":"PC3", "location":"Berlin"}
]
}

var mergedObject = {computers: []};

for(var computer of computers.computers){

  var server = (({ OS }) => ({ OS }))(servers.servers.find(function(server){return server.ServerName === computer.ComputerName}));
  // Get only "OS" property of server
  
  var cmp = {...computer, ...server};
  mergedObject.computers.push(cmp);
}

console.log(mergedObject);
```

---

**UPDATE**

According to OP's second question, I updated the snippet as following:

```js
var servers = {
  0:{ServerName:"PC1", OS:"Windows", PRPName: "NO_PRP", SLA: "gold"}, 
  1:{ServerName:"PC2", OS:"Linux", PRPName: "NO_PRP", SLA: "silver"},
  2:{ServerName:"PC3", OS:"Windows", PRPName: "NO_PRP", SLA: "bronz"},
  3:{ServerName:"PC4", OS:"Windows", PRPName: "NO_PRP", SLA: "gold"}, 
  4:{ServerName:"PC5", OS:"Linux", PRPName: "NO_PRP", SLA: "bronz"},
  5:{ServerName:"PC6", OS:"Windows", PRPName: "NO_PRP", SLA: "bronz"},
  6:{ServerName:"PC7", OS:"Windows", PRPName: "NO_PRP", SLA: "bronz"},
};

var computers = {
  0:{Name:"PC1", location:"Amsterdam", PatchStatus: "true", RebootPending: "true"}, 
  1:{Name:"PC2", location:"London", PatchStatus: "true", RebootPending: "true"},
  2:{Name:"PC3", location:"Berlin", PatchStatus: "true", RebootPending: "false"},
  3:{Name:"PC4", location:"Berlin", PatchStatus: "false", RebootPending: "true"},
  4:{Name:"PC5", location:"London", PatchStatus: "true", RebootPending: "false"},
  5:{Name:"PC6", location:"Amsterdam", PatchStatus: "true", RebootPending: "true"},
  6:{Name:"PC9", location:"Amsterdam", PatchStatus: "true", RebootPending: "true"}
};

// Please note that Objects must have a key, so I added 0, 1, 2 etc as keys.

var mergedArray = [];

for(var computer of Object.values(computers)){

  var findItem = Object.values(servers).find(function(server){return server.ServerName === computer.Name});
  if(!findItem){
    continue;
  }
  
  var {ServerName, ...server} = findItem;
  // {ServerName, ...server} is  called "desctructring". You set "ServerName" property in "ServerName" a variable 
  // and all the other properties to "server" variable
  
  var cmp = {...computer, ...server};
  mergedArray.push(cmp);
}

console.log(mergedArray);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thx, maby a bit stupid question but how do you merge it if you have it like this?

var servers = {
  {"ServerName":"PC1", "OS":"Windows"}, 
  {"ServerName":"PC2", "OS":"Linux"},
  {"ServerName":"PC3", "OS":"Windows"}
}

var computers = {
  {"ComputerName":"PC1", "location":"Amsterdam"}, 
  {"ComputerName":"PC2", "location":"London"},
  {"ComputerName":"PC3", "location":"Berlin"}
}

Comment: I edited the answer. But please note that you cannot have an object like `{{a:1},{a:2}}` as it is invalid. You need to either have keys or use it as array like `[{a:1},{a:2}]`

Comment: it looks like he makes a nested JSON because of this 
var mergedObject = {computers: []}; because now it is computer: Array instead of array. ( i hope i am explaining it correct???)

Comment: Hi, i doing something wrong he only graps the first entry and then he passes that information to all other entries? so the code does not check every line? Maby i can post the more actual data i am using because i need to past more options then only the OS option?

Comment: Edited the answer again :)

Comment: Thx,  i gone test it again :)

Comment: Sorry, my bad :) Fixed it. Instead of excluding `ServerName`, excluded `OS` property. It should work now.

Comment: thx, for your help. iam getting this error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot destructure property `ServerName` of 'undefined' or 'null'. it is because the servername and name are not the same some times, is possible that the script only combine the 2 entry's that are the same and the other entry's he does not do anything. (like silentlycontinue?)

Comment: the Name entry is uppercase and the ServerName entry is lower case.  :(

Comment: Updated the answer. Btw, perhaps you need to compare lowercased or uppercased properties. `server.ServerName.toLowerCase() === computer.Name.toLowerCase()`

Answer (score 0):

Here's my approach.

Step 1:  Build an *index*.  This will be an object that has keys that are the values of the `ServerName` property of each *server*, and the value is the server object itself minus the key - no need to store it twice, and you actually are going to use the key name from the *computer*, not the key name from the *server* (they're different: `ServerName` vs. `Name`).

Start with an empty object `{}` and then for each *server* object, add a property that maps the `ServerName` to the object itself.  This can be done with [for ... of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of#Iterating_over_an_Array) syntax to iterate over the array.

The index should look like this:

```json
{ PC1: { OS: 'Windows', PRPName: 'NO_PRP', SLA: 'gold' },
  PC2: { OS: 'Linux', PRPName: 'NO_PRP', SLA: 'silver' },
  PC3: { OS: 'Windows', PRPName: 'NO_PRP', SLA: 'bronz' },
  PC4: { OS: 'Windows', PRPName: 'NO_PRP', SLA: 'gold' },
  PC5: { OS: 'Linux', PRPName: 'NO_PRP', SLA: 'bronz' },
  PC6: { OS: 'Windows', PRPName: 'NO_PRP', SLA: 'bronz' } }
```

Step 2: *Join*.  This means that you return an array where each object of the `computers` array becomes an object with all the fields of the *computer*, plus all the fields of the *server* with matching `Name` value.  We find that object by accessing `index[value]` where `value` is the value of the `computer.Name`.

To do this in a clean way, we can use destructuring to peel off the joining property names from the object.

There's really only two components to the code here.  A `for ... of` to build the index with a property assignment, and a `map` to join the tables.  The rest is just juggling the properties around using [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Unpacking_fields_from_objects_passed_as_function_parameter) and [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) syntax.

**EDIT:** Because you changed your source data format and key names in your question, I added a utility function called `arrayFromObject` to convert an object with integer keys to an array and updated the rest of this answer to match the specifics of your new question.

Here's a full runnable snippet.

```js
var servers = {
  0:{ServerName:"PC1", OS:"Windows", PRPName: "NO_PRP", SLA: "gold"},
  1:{ServerName:"PC2", OS:"Linux", PRPName: "NO_PRP", SLA: "silver"},
  2:{ServerName:"PC3", OS:"Windows", PRPName: "NO_PRP", SLA: "bronz"},
  3:{ServerName:"PC4", OS:"Windows", PRPName: "NO_PRP", SLA: "gold"},
  4:{ServerName:"PC5", OS:"Linux", PRPName: "NO_PRP", SLA: "bronz"},
  5:{ServerName:"PC6", OS:"Windows", PRPName: "NO_PRP", SLA: "bronz"}
};

var computers = {
  0:{Name:"PC1", location:"Amsterdam", PatchStatus: "true", RebootPending: "true"},
  1:{Name:"PC2", location:"London", PatchStatus: "true", RebootPending: "true"},
  2:{Name:"PC3", location:"Berlin", PatchStatus: "true", RebootPending: "false"},
  3:{Name:"PC4", location:"Berlin", PatchStatus: "false", RebootPending: "true"},
  4:{Name:"PC5", location:"London", PatchStatus: "true", RebootPending: "false"},
  5:{Name:"PC6", location:"Amsterdam", PatchStatus: "true", RebootPending: "true"}
};

// make an array from the integer keys of an object
function arrayFromObject(obj) {
  let array = [];
  for (let x in obj) {
    array[+x] = obj[x];
  }
  return array;
}

let index = {};
 for ({ ServerName, ...server } of arrayFromObject(servers) ) index[ServerName] = server;

let result = arrayFromObject(computers).map(
   ({ Name, ...computer }) => ({ Name, ...computer, ...index[Name] }));

console.log(result);
```

---

#### A note on functional programming and performance.

The more concise [functional](https://itnext.io/how-to-understand-reduce-d246b7a70f78) way to build the index would have been to use [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).  This works too, but I'm paranoid that it will not perform as well as using `for ... of` because the implementation may build a new accumulator object on each iteration.  I'm not certain if the JavaScript engine you are using will perform the optimization to prevent that from occurring.  I did not measure the performance to know for sure, and it would be platform specific anyway.  But this is actually the code I would have preferred to use, if it performs well.

```js
    let index = arrayFromObject(servers).reduce(
      (index, { ServerName, ...server }) => ({ ...index, [ServerName]: server }), {});
```

Comment: @kleineties.  That was a significant change.  But I've updated my answer to match the new details of your question.